# OpenCV to Identify objects from training video set and then test them against another video

Tags: c++, image, opencv, object-detection

I have been tasked to use OpenCV and C++

1. Read a set of videos for creating a set of images/learning.
2. Classify objects seen in the videos
3. Label the images
4. test against series of test videos to check objects were identified as expected. draw a rectangle around them and label.

I am new to OpenCV however happy to program in C++ as soon as approach is formed. I am also planning to write my own functions at a later stage.

I need your help in formning right way of solution approach as I have to identify household objects [cup, soft toy, phone, camera, keyboard) from a stream of video and then test on another stream of video. The original video has depth information as well but not sure how to use it to my benefit.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is to find the correct way of doing it. e.g. the video has a image and depth component. Not sure how do identify different objects from a streaming video? Another issue is to formulate whether I should grab frames and store as image or should i use some sort of in memory processing.<Br> Last issue is on how can I then label a test video with the objects identified in the first step.

Comment: cbm, there is no silver bullet in computer vision. different kinds of objects require different handling. be more specific about *what* you are trying to identify(well *objects* are not helpful at all), else noone can help you

Comment: btw, asking on SO is NO replacement for own research ..

Comment: Thx berak, appreciate your inputs. I am learning to be specific as I am being questioned. Training video is a kinect video having household obj such as doll, cup, mug, mobile etc. with a plain background. Problem is to identify them as the video is continuous. Once my program has learnt from that next is to validate against similar video. All I am looking for a better approach. I am thinking  to grab frames as images and then isolate obj from them and test them against test video. The problem with this approach is that I will have a big list of frames and learner is going to run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Support vector machine (SVM) , Feature extraction (e.g. SIFT/SURF) , SVM training and SVM testing. And, for drawing Rectangle, read about findContour(), drawContour() in openCV.

**Approach:**

- Detect objects (e.g. car/plane etc.). Store the points of its contours
- Extract some features of that object using SIFT/SURF
- Based upon the extracted features, classify the object using SVM (the input for SVM will be the extracted features)
- And if the SVM says -Yes! it is a car. Then, draw a rectangle around it using the points of its contour which you had stored in first step.